# What is the scope of free() in dynamically allocated memory?

Tags: c, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-allocation

Let's say I have the following code:

```
typedef struct {
  int numBars;
  BarType *bars;
} fooType;

foo = (fooType *) malloc(sizeof(fooType));
foo->bars = (BarType *) malloc(sizeof(barType));
```

Will calling free(foo) also free the bars or do I need to do this:

```
free(foo->bars);
free(foo);
```

Intuitively, I feel that calling free(foo) should be enough - if I don't need to call free(foo->numBars) I shouldn't need to call free(foo->bars). But I didn't have to manually allocate memory  for numBars, while I did for bars.

Comment: The lesson you learned today is that you should *never* rely on intuition when programming in C. (Or get a better intuition.)

Comment: You don't need to call free on numBar because you didn't malloc it in the first place. You malloc'd bars, so you have to free it at some point.

Comment: Keep in mind that `mallic` and `free` have no idea what's in the block of allocated memory; it's just a blob. Therefore, free has no idea that the memory pointed to by `foo` contains a pointer, let alone a pointer to another malloced block. Also, there is no garbage collector in C to detect that the second block is orphaned and should be freed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every `malloc` you need one `free`. Nothing is done "automatically" for you.

Note that, contrary to your claim,  you do *not* actually have to allocate any memory for `bars`, just as you don't have to allocate memory for `numBars`. However, you *are* allocating memory for `*bars`.

A single star can make a big difference in C...

Comment: @WeatherVane: No, the pointer won't have gone out of scope. But the pointee will have stopped to exist. Which is bad.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The OP got totally confused by a single asterisk. I think nitpicking is in order here :-)

Comment: +1 @WeatherVane whether it is reallocated or not is irrelevant. Once the memory pointed to by `foo` is handed to `free` that pointer becomes indeterminate. Dereferencing it invokes *undefined behavior*, whether it "works" or not. If `foo->bars` is the sole pointer variable in existence holding the address returned from the non-freed `bars` allocation when `foo` was freed, no well-formed code can stop the ensuing memory leak. One can stave off `foo->bars` in some other pointer variable (a local `void* p = foo->bars;` for example), if truly set on freeing non-inversely to the allocation order.

Comment: OK I'll rewrite my point, *if* you have used `malloc()` to obtain memory for a structure that contains another pointer to memory also obtained with `malloc()`, free them in reverse order. It was such a simple point to someone unsure about freeing memory, but you've made a lot of it.

Comment: @KerrekSB this is how I wrapped my mind around it. It makes sense that when I call free(foo), I AM getting rid of the pointer to bars. Although the actual data I previously allocated memory to is still there, I just have no way to access it anymore due to having lost the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

By using this: foo = (fooType *) malloc(sizeof(fooType)); You are actually allocating memory for the struct 'fooType' which just has the pointer to hold the address of the other allocated block of memory )(malloced for barType).

You have to explicitly free each malloced memory. Otherwise, if you use only free(foo). It will cause memory leaks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)!!

Answer (score -1):

`free()` is very simple:  It frees the memory block passed to it—which must have come from `malloc()`.  It does not do any cascade frees or other cleanup.  It also does not NULL the pointer to help catch simple logic errors.

```
free(foo->bars);
free(foo);
foo = NULL;   /* good idea to do this, unless `foo` is going out of scope soon */
```